# To display the category image in the page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have used the Taxonomy Images plugin to store the image for each category. Now i want to display the category images. But i could not find any settings to diplay those images. Is there any better plugin for display the category images with the category name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the category images just use this:

```
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    print '<ul>';
    foreach( (array) $terms as $term ) {
        print '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'detail' ) . '</li>';
    }
    print '</ul>';
}
```

By default shows the 'category'